# How to tell whether the page was printer when using window.print()?

Tags: javascript

Using JavaScript I can write

```
window.print();
```

This will show the print dialog for the user to print the screen. My question is how can I tell whether the page was actually printed or whether the user clicked cancel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't.  The printer diaglog box does not pass anything back to the browser once the JS calls it so there is nothing to listen or check for after the print dialog box is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

Look at the [MDN docs for the `window.print` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.print), and in particular at the description of what the method does:

> Opens the Print Dialog to print the current document.

Note that it does *not* say "Print the current document".  The browser deliberately (and rightly) only passes certain limited data back to the script.  This is for all kinds of good security and privacy reasons.

Answer (score 0):

there's no easy way. print() doesn't return the result.
My idea would be...

Define some CSS file, include it with `media="print"`, have an attribute like `background-image: url('i-am-printed.php');`
In i-am-printed.js you may write some information.

Excuse ma, that's nothing i've ever tried. In addition, it does not provide the needed information instantly. You can only check the results later.

Comment: in a similar way - without server-side scripting you may access images +some identification-params dummy.gif?userId=12345 and review access later

Comment: This is a clever idea, but the style sheet would probably be loaded for a print *preview* as well